# Facebook Share Customize Message Field

Tags: javascript, facebook, url, anchor, message

How can I customize the message field with Facebook share... You used to be able able to use one of the share URLs with a ?message= parameter but that no longer works... Here is what I currently use for the contents but I can't change the users default post:

```
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=URL&t=TITLE">FBshare</a>
```

Using URL-Javascript I can alter the innerHTML of the post-field's text-area after I have gone to the URL... but I guess I can't send that information after the user has gone to the Facebook URL and left my page right?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Customize message field on Facebook Share](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9591655/customize-message-field-on-facebook-share)

Answer (score 0):

I do believe that the old sharer.php is in the process of being deprecated.

You should convert over to using the send plugin https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/send/

or the like plugin https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

Make sure your Open Graph meta tags are in order (this is where you specify title) See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/

Comment: With the send plugin can I customize the message field?

Comment: There is no message attribute of the send plugin.  BTW, if I answered your original question correctly, please mark/accept my answer.  Thank you.

Comment: I'm looking for a workaround to change the innerHTML of the textArea of face book's share feature.

Comment: Forget about the old Facebook sharer.php feature.  It won't be around much longer (see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/share/ for deprecation notice) :)

Comment: Nope, as I stated above, I'm looking for a way to customize the message field.

Comment: You cannot do it via your script.  The only way to customize the message field is to adjust the og: meta tags on the website whos URL is being shared.